# Show that the following map is surjective

Tags: number-theory, curves

Situation:

Consider the curves $ C_1 = x^2 + y^2 +x^2y^2 = 1 $ and $C_2 = w^2 = 1 - z^4 .$

Define a map $\lambda$ from $C_1$ to $C_2$ with $\lambda(x,y) = (x,(1+x^2)y)$.

This map should be bijective. injective was ok, but I failed to show that this map is surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any point $(z,w)$ in $C_2$ is the image of the point $(x,y)=(z,\frac w {1+z^{2}})$. All you have to do is to verify the condition $x^{2}+x^{2}+x^{2}y^{2}=1$ using the condition $w^{2}=1-z^{4}$.